# How to have multiple if statements within named range

Tags: excel, if-statement, named-ranges, nested-if

I am looking to find out how I can write the following if statements within the one line. Unfortunately the IF statements work individually but whenever I combine it, it gives me a #VALUE error.

```
=IF(A1=OUT,C1,IF(A1=INT,C1,IF(A1=IN,C1,"Not Found")))
```

OUT, INT and IN are all named ranges within my file  and I have worked out the reason why I get the error and I think this is due to the first statement not being true and from what I can see its not moving onto the next part of the formula.

The problem I have is when I reach cell A8, the value in this cell now belongs to the named range INT and this is when the formula shows the #VALUE error.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could please advise where I am going wrong and how I can fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Btw the following are my named ranges in my file:

```
A1:A7 = OUT 
A8:A10 = INT 
A11:A17 = IN
```

and the results are within the following ranges:

```
C1:C7 = Lose
C8:C10 = Draw 
C11:C17 = Win
```

What I would like the formula to do is if any of the values that I have in Column A belong to any of the named ranges, I would like it to show the correct result.

For example cell A8 has the value "A8" and this belongs to the named range INT so I would like the IF statement to work so that it shows the value Draw. If I am in cell A11 this has the value "A11" which belongs to the named range "IN" so therefore I would like the formula to show me the value Win.

The following is an image of my document.

[image]

Comment: Are all named ranges single cells? or are they ranges of cells?

Comment: hi apologies. The following are my named ranges:

Comment: A1:A7 = OUT, A8:A10 = INT, A11:A17 = IN

Comment: Column C has the following ranges for the results

Comment: C1:C7 = Lose, C8:C10 = Draw, C11:C17 = Win

Comment: What are you asking? If cell A1 is in named range, or if its value is found in a named range? Currently you are asking if A1=A1:A7, which is why you're getting an error.

Comment: What I would like is for it to work for all the ranges. So for example if I am on cell A8 and this does not equal a value from the named range "OUT" but INT then I would like it to show the value "Draw". At present it only works on the true element of the IF function...

Comment: Please show some test data and expected outcome in the original post.  Also amend the post to include your clarifications that are currently in comments.

Comment: Please show visually either with a picture or a data table in the OP the data and desired outcome.  Right now it sounds like you want the formula in Column A to reference itself, which is not possible.

Comment: see my answer below, you may need to refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching inside a named range, if the searching item is not found, excel will return error. so A8=OUT at the 8th row works out error and the same is the case with row number 10. So, if you check error for searching, this will be fixed. You can use the below method to fix this issue. Use this formula in first row  (D1) and copy it to rest of the cells.

```
=IF(IFERROR(A1=OUT,FALSE),C1,IF(IFERROR(A1=INT,FALSE),C1,IF(A1=IN,C1,"Not Found")))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott and Karpark for your responses. I have tried the formula from Karpak and this has fixed my issues, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The if statements will only look at the first value in the named ranges.  You need to use Something that will iterate or search through the ranges:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,OUT,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,IN,0)),ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,INT,0))),C1,"Not Found")
```

[image]

But this will always return true as the values that are being tested are in the named ranges being referenced.  So a simpler formula will give the same results.

```
=C1
```